# Add items from Array with sign $

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4, xcode4.2, ipad-2

**I have an Array , if I print that in console it shows**

```
Price Array=(
    "$100",
    "$300"
)
```

I need to add add objects at each index and show it in label. Please suggest any idea, in this case how it will show 400 with $ sign?
**I tried this in view did load**

```
for (int j=0; j<[cartArray2 count]; j++)
    {
        itemPrize =[prizelabel.text floatValue];
        tempVar=itemPrize;
        total=total+tempVar;
        NSString *strTotalAmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",total];
        prizelabel.text=strTotalAmt;
    }
    NSLog( @"Toatl= %f",total);`
```

where in interface float itemPrize,tempVar,total

---

**This is what i did**

```
for (int j=0; j<[cartArray2 count]; j++)
{
    NSMutableString *cleanedText = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];

    NSString *newRecord = [[cartArray2 objectAtIndex:j] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [[cartArray2 objectAtIndex:j] length])];
    [cleanedText appendFormat:@"%@\n", newRecord];

    NSLog(@"Cleaned=%@", cleanedText);
    itemPrize =[cleanedText intValue];
    tempVar=itemPrize;
    total=total+tempVar;
    NSString *strTotalAmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total];
    prizelabel.text=strTotalAmt;
}
NSLog( @"Toatl= %d",total);
```

Comment: @Ajit Satarkar can we see some code?

Comment: @Thilo I tried this in View did load NSLog(@"Price Array=%@",cartArray2);
    for (int j=0; j<[cartArray2 count]; j++)
    {
        itemPrize =[prizelabel.text floatValue];
        tempVar=itemPrize;
        total=total+tempVar;
        NSString *strTotalAmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",total];
        prizelabel.text=strTotalAmt;
    } where float itemPrize,tempVar, total is declared globally.

Comment: You need to get rid of the "$" before calling floatValue. And add it later when printing the result.

Comment: @Thilo Actually that $ sign default-ally comes because i got this items by parsing JSON

Comment: I know, but you can use string manipulation functions (substring comes to mind) to cut it out.

Comment: @Thilo Thank you it works properly now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of $ sign you should try: `[[itemPrize componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"] objectAtIndex:1];`. Then you should use `stringWithFormat` method to do the string formatting.